# MySQL add balance from previous rows

Tags: mysql

I’ve tried a few things I’ve seen on here but it doesn’t work in my case, the balance on each row seems to duplicate.

Anyway I have a table that holds mortgage transactions, that table has a Column that stores an interest added value or a payment value.

So I might have:

```
Balance: 100,000
Interest added 100 - balance 100,100
Payment made -500 - balance 99,600

Interest added 100 - balance 99,700
Payment made -500 - balance 99,200
```

What I’m looking for is a query to pull all of these in date order newest first and summing the balance in a column depending on whether it has interest or payment (the one that doesn’t will be null) so at the end of the rows it will have the current liability

I can’t remember what the query I tried was but it ended up duplicating rows and the balance was weird

[image]

Sample structure and data:

```
CREATE TABLE account(
id int not null primary key auto_increment,
account_name varchar(50),
starting_balance float(10,6)

);

CREATE TABLE account_transaction(
id int not null primary key auto_increment,
account_id int NOT NULL,
date datetime,
interest_amount int DEFAULT null,
payment_amount float(10,6) DEFAULT NULL

);

INSERT INTO account (account_name,starting_balance) VALUES('Test Account','100000');

INSERT INTO account_transaction (account_id,date,interest_amount,payment_amount) VALUES(1,'2020-10-01 00:00:00',300,null);

INSERT INTO account_transaction (account_id,date,interest_amount,payment_amount) VALUES(1,'2020-10-01 00:00:00',null,-500);

INSERT INTO account_transaction (account_id,date,interest_amount,payment_amount) VALUES(1,'2020-11-01 00:00:00',300,null);

INSERT INTO account_transaction (account_id,date,interest_amount,payment_amount) VALUES(1,'2020-11-05 00:00:00',-500,null);
```

So interest will be added on to the rolling balance, and the starting balance is stored against the account - if we have to have a transaction added for this then ok. Then when a payment is added it can be either negative or positive to decrease the balance moving to each row.

So above example i'd expect to see something along the lines of:

[image]

I hope this makes it clearer

Comment: 'pull all of these in date' - how can you do that there is no date in your table (apparently). Please add table definition and proper representative sample data together with expected output as text to the question.

Comment: Please, provide your data structure, a query you tried, a screenshot from your table.

Comment: Provide also **precise** version of your MySQL server.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the table, it has interest in one column snd null in payment or vice versa. Payment is added as negative in case it needs to be adjusted.

Comment: Screenshots are not useful. Source data must be provided as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (if you can't do it - as formatted textual table). PS. Where initial balance must be taken from?

Comment: I don’t know how it’s not useful it clearly shows a column for interest which would be added to the balance and payment which would be also added to the balance and because it’s a negative number it would decrease the balance. The starting balance would come from a joined table by the mortgage Id which has a column for starting_balance. Surely can work from that?

Comment: @Akina i have updated with some basic table creation and a screenshot of excel that i'd expect to be seeing happen. THe balance column carries it down. I added the starting balance as a + transaction to get the first balance

Comment: `100000` cannot be stored in `float(10,6)`.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH
starting_dates AS ( SELECT id account_id, MIN(`date`) startdate
                    FROM account_transaction 
                    GROUP BY id ),
combine AS ( SELECT 0 id, 
                    starting_dates.account_id, 
                    starting_dates.startdate `date`, 
                    0 interest_amount, 
                    account.starting_balance payment_amount
             FROM account
             JOIN starting_dates ON account.id = starting_dates.account_id
             UNION ALL
             SELECT id,
                    account_id, 
                    `date`, 
                    interest_amount, 
                    payment_amount
             FROM account_transaction )
SELECT DATE(`date`) `Date`,
       CASE WHEN interest_amount = 0     THEN 'Balance Brought Forward'
            WHEN payment_amount IS NULL  THEN 'Interest Added'
            WHEN interest_amount IS NULL THEN 'Payment Added'
            ELSE 'Unknown transaction type'
            END `Desc`,
       CASE WHEN interest_amount = 0 THEN ''
            ELSE COALESCE(interest_amount, 0)
            END Interest,
       COALESCE(payment_amount, 0) Payment,
       SUM(COALESCE(payment_amount, 0) + COALESCE(interest_amount, 0))
           OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY id) Balance
FROM combine
ORDER BY id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=53891240d55a8179fa1da4d7fb681885)

PS. Source data provided (row with `id=4`) was altered according to desired output provided. Source structure was altered, `FLOAT(10,6)` which is not compatible with provided values was replaced with `DECIMAL`.

PPS. The presence of more than one account is allowed.

Comment: Sorry I didn’t respond earlier. It looks quite complex that one, I’ve seen other simpler ones and the worry here is that symfony query builder (doctrine) might not handle this query. I’m not sure. Is there a simpler solution if say we don’t join it to the mortgage table and just feed it a starting balance?